# How can i check if the ssl binding on a web ap has expired or is soon going to expire in Azure?

Tags: azure, powershell

Im using

```
 az webapp config ssl list --resource-group  "$resourcegroup" | ConvertFrom-Json
```

but this gives back all certificates.
The issue is that under the bindings in Azure for the web app it had an expired certificate.
Can i check the actual bindings and if they are soon going to expire using powershell and the az cmdlets ?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter it in powershell:

**Expired:**

```
az webapp config ssl list --resource-group "$resourcegroup" | ConvertFrom-Json | Where-Object {$_.expirationDate -lt (Get-Date)}
```